# Как правильно повернуть текст в HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Использую `writing-mode: sideways-lr;`, но как оказалось это не самый лучший вариант в плане кросс-браузерности. Не могу разобраться почему в этом случае `rotate()` не работает. На первом скрине, как должно, а на втором, как получается.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? На скриншоте всё повёрнуто - значит, видимо, работает. Что не так?

Comment: Да, не так сказал) В общем получается не то, чего ожидал, не могу понять почему он залазиет за границы другого блока и вообще расположился недо-центре

Comment: Потому что вы задали блоку слишком маленькие размеры и текст в него чисто геометрически не может влезть, наверное?

Comment: Увы нет, даже если дать больше, то он все равно на N-пикселей выходит и не поддается никаким законам физики

Comment: Покажите соответствующий пример, а то непонятно, о чём речь

Comment: Задайте блоку заголовка ширину, в которую он мог бы свободно помещаться без переноса слов. Затем вращайте (rotate) и перемещайте (translate) этот прямоугольник, чтобы поставить в нужное место.

Comment: Иначе никак? Мне кажется код будет громадным и не эффективным, особенно в адапте. Буду пробовать, может получится поделиться опытом. Спасибо за внимание!)

Comment: @СемёнГолган, на сайте все корректно повернуто. Ошибка больше не воспроизводится?

Comment: Прикрепил еще один скриншот, я пытаюсь найти способ, чтобы блок обновился после поворота и ему не мешал "призрачный" блок, как на скриншоте